# Getting the Error Code: 6'101 when using Connected Objects for my TCRM Recipe

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, saql, google-analytics, tableau-crm

I am testing a recipe that accesses the data from "connected objects" instead of a data set, selected only necessary columns. I performed sync of objects a few hours before. Getting the following error:

> "We can't load the preview. Please try previewing the node again. If the problem persists, contact Salesforce Customer Support with this error code: 6'101, Preview ID: xyz"

I wonder if that's due to my object sync being performed a few hours before? Or it might be another issue?

Accessing direct objects for the first time so learning about the best practices. Suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is just a timeout on the viewer (those seem to occur more lately). Does the recipe save successfully?  Are you able to get data out?  If the object is connected and correct fields added (and the synch is successful per Data Manager),that is mostly likely the issue.  Good luck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).